# Silverlight Value Converter

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I have a Value Converter running for an incoming string value from the database, to set the appropriate icon for a gender. The value coming in must be either M or F, and either one will display a male or female icon respectively. The Binding is working to some extent, in that the picture appears, but it is only displaying one set of icons for either value.

The value converter code is as follows:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var gender = (string)value;
  Uri uri;
  uri = gender == "F" ?
          new Uri("../Resources/Icons/female_user.png", UriKind.Relative) :
          new Uri("../Resources/Icons/male_user.png", UriKind.Relative);
  return uri;
}


public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and the XAML is as follows

```
 <Image Margin="8" Width="35" Height="35"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Source="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource genderConverter}}" />
```

The resource is cited in the usercontrol.resources and all is properly bound I assume. So why does the converter persistently return only one value?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "is only displaying one set of icons for either value"? (2) What happens when you set a breakpoint in your code? Does it ever return an unexpected icon?

Comment: As Ken says, set a breakpoint: the debugger should make things clear.  One possibility is that the binding source is returning e.g. "m" and "f" so the case-sensitive match to "F" never passes.  Another "doh!" possibility is that someone has accidentally created the same placeholder icon for both genders and forgotten to update it with final artwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was a gender.Trim() to get rid of all white spaces.

```
var gender = value.ToString();
        try
        {
            return gender.Trim() == "F" ? "../Resources/Icons/male_user.png" : "../Resources/Icons/female_user.png";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
```

Thats took care of it all, and it works. Thanks for the answers and "doh!" possibilites though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

                var gender = (string)value;
                Uri uri;
                uri = gender == "F" ?
                        new Uri("../Resources/Icons/female_user.png", UriKind.Relative) :
                        new Uri("../Resources/Icons/male_user.png", UriKind.Relative);
                BitmapImage img_Gender = new BitmapImage(uri);
                return img_Gender;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I got it solved, all I needed was a gender.Trim() to get out all the white spaces.